# Find the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $5\cdot{}^xC_y=3\cdot{}^7C_3$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that  $5\cdot{}^xC_y=3\cdot{}^7C_3$

I am very new to number theory and combinatorics, so I could not proceed much. I tried to break ${} ^7C_3$ in the factorial form and then tried to simply, but it was not of any help.

So, any hint or answer will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your notation mean.

Comment: @JefLaga That is a multiplication

Comment: @WilliamElliot C from combinatorical notation

Comment: Is the question "solve $5\binom{x}{y}=3\binom{7}{3}$"?

Comment: Yes, it is....i am new LaTeX user, so I used that notation

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You can produce the multiplication symbol $\cdot$ by typing \cdot when you are in math mode.  You can produce $\binom{x}{y}$ by typing \binom{x}{y} when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
5{x \choose y} & = 3{7 \choose 3} \\
& = 3 \cdot \frac{7!}{3!(7-4)!} \\
& = 3 \cdot \frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4!}{3!\cdot4!} \\
& = 3\cdot \frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5}{3!} \\
& = 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \\
& = 105 \\
\implies {x \choose y} & = 21 \\
\end{align}

We know that $x$ is at most $21$, because the values are increasing as $x$ increases. Obvious solutions are $(21,1)$ and $(21,20)$. Looking at [Pascal's Triangle](http://mathforum.org/dr.cgi/pascal.cgi?rows=21), we see that $(7,2)$ and $(7,5)$ are answers as well.

Hence there are $4$ solutions which are $(7,2), (7,5), (21,1),(21,20)$.